# Deserializing JSON into byrefrence ParametrizedConstructor object with Json.NET

Tags: vb.net, constructor, parameterized

Below is my JSON formated String

{"AliasName": "ysiCountryInfo", "DataClass": {"Description":"United States 111","Code":"usa","WriteOffTaxPointAdjustment":0,"IndexationRounding":6}}

I would like to deserialize object into below class

Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports BaseApp.ysiBaseData
Imports Common.DataClasses
Imports Systems

Namespace DataClasses

```
Public Class JSONFormatClass(Of ItemType)

    Private _Alias As String
    Public Property AliasName() As String
        Get
            Return _Alias
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Alias = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _DataClass As ItemType
    Public Property DataClass() As ItemType
        Get
            Return _DataClass
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ItemType)
            _DataClass = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

End Namespace

Where Property "DataClass" is type of any class from "Common.DataClasses".

And all class in this has Parametrized constructor which accept ByRef LoginCredential Object.

And My Code is below:

Dim loginData As New ysiLoginData()

```
   With loginData
     .Server = "xxxxx"
     .Platform = ServerType.SqlServer
     .Database = "xxxx"    
     .UserName = "xx"
     .Password = "xxxxx"
     .DeveloperMode = True
  End With
```

Dim SessionKey As New ysiSessionKey(loginData)

Dim strJSON As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.Form.ToString())

Dim objJSON As JSONFormatClass(Of ysiCountryInfo) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSONFormatClass(Of ysiCountryInfo))(strJSON)

json string format : {"AliasName": "ysiCountryInfo", "DataClass": {"Description":"United States 111","Code":"usa","WriteOffTaxPointAdjustment":0,"IndexationRounding":6}}

here "ysiCountryInfo" is class type into which i would like to convert my "DataClass" property. "ysiCountryInfo" has parametrized constructor  which requires parameter of "ysiSessionKey" by ref.

Dim objCountryInfo as New ysiCountryInfo(ysiSessionKey)

I am getting Error into JsonSerializerInternalReader.js file of JSON at line # 808

object createdObject = contract.ParametrizedConstructor.Invoke(constructorParameters.Values.ToArray());

Because constructorParameters.Values is Null

Please help me to solve this problem ASAP.

Thanks 
Dhiren Mistry

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i was implemented its incorrectly.

I had solve this problem by modifying my Generic Class DataClass Property As Below.

```
Private _DataClass As ItemType
Public Property DataClass() As ItemType
            Get
                If _DataClass Is Nothing Then
                    Dim loginData As New ysiLoginData()
                    With loginData
                        .Server = "xxxx"
                        .Platform = ServerType.SqlServer
                        .Database = "xxx"
                        .UserName = "xx"
                        .Password = "xxx"
                        .DeveloperMode = True
                    End With

                    Dim SessionKey As New ysiSessionKey(loginData)

                    Dim args As Object() = {SessionKey}

                    _DataClass = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance("YSI.Common", String.Format("{0}", GetType(ItemType).ToString()), True, BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public, Nothing, args, Nothing, Nothing).Unwrap(), ItemType)

                End If
                Return _DataClass
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As ItemType)
                _DataClass = value
            End Set
        End Property
```